# Drop down change not firing in Bootstrap modal

Tags: asp.net, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-modal

I am using aspx page with master page, and opening in bootstrap modal popup using below code

```
$('#MyPopup').load('WebForm1.aspx', function () {
     $('#MyPopup1').modal('show'); 
});
```

in 'WebForm1.aspx' I have a dropdown as shown  below

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="dpStatus" CssClass="form-control" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True">
    <asp:ListItem Text="Select Fruit" Value="0" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Mango" Value="1" />
    <asp:ListItem Text="Apple" Value="2" />
</asp:DropDownList>
```

My problem is, the change event of above drop down is not firing in my code behind. Only page load for the base page(the page where we open the popup) is firing while we changing drop down.

Comment: If you want to fire events in code behind, you must invoke a postback. Alternativelly, just do what you want to do with JS

Comment: I have already set the 'autopostback =true' for the dropdown. You mean something like firing button click on change event of dropdown from jQuery?

Comment: Try to look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20240124/autopostback-for-dropdownlist-in-asp-net